# testApt for android-library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an **android library** project. I want to have dependency injection working (**apt** annotation processing) inside of JUnit's tests. The DI framework I use is **Dagger2**. 
All of the dagger's components/modules/classes need to **be test-only** i.e. @Component interface and @Module class are all defined in **src/test/java** (NOT in src/main/java)

My gradle files are as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}
```

and the core.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // ------- dagger 2 -----------------------------
    testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
    testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
    testProvided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Error:(42, 0) Could not find method testApt() for arguments [com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I know the new DSL method is *testAnnotationProcessor* but I still use  `com.neenbedankt.android-apt` and haven't switched to Jack compiler yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be really simple. I just needed to upgrade `android-apt` plugin version to **1.8** which support **testApt**

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```